# ImageButton is ListView, starting new activity onClick, Android

Tags: android

I am sure this is answered somewhere, but can't find it.

I have a ListView of user goals...I have a button on the top where users can add a goal:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    style="@style/secondaryBackground"
    tools:context="android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife.GoalsList">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addgoal"
        style="@style/FloatingActionButtonOrange"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="add goal"
        android:onClick="btnRemoveClick" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addgoal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/goalsection">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Goal Name"
            android:id="@+id/goalname"
            android:padding="10dp"
            style="@style/orangetextlarger"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The AddGoal button is not really part of the ListView...it is not part of the data being retrieved..I've tried to have the button click start a new activity in the adapter, but I have not been able to; I added some code within the GetItemView function, but it seems findViewById cannot be resolved

```
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_goals_list, null);
    }

    // use midwifefirm as item view/list

    super.getItemView(object, view, parent);

    // find in layout the practice name
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalname);

    //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("goalname"));

    mAddGoal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addgoal);
    mAddGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GoalListAdapter.this, AddGoal.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I was also thinking within the ImageButton in the Layout, I could set an onClick function there?

Apologies, I know this is probably answered somewhere, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the inflated view

You should use the inflated view when finding the view with [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)). You should have:

`mAddGoal = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addgoal);`

instead of:

`mAddGoal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addgoal);`

---

## Remove the XML onClick

If you are going down the route of setting an onClickListener, then you should remove the onClick attribute set on the ImageView in XML.

Remove the following from the element `@+id/addgoal`:

`android:onClick="btnRemoveClick"`

---

## Passing in the context

In order to start an activity from your class, you need to pass in the context. An example is shown below:

```
public class ParseAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {
    private Context mContext;

    public ParseAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        mAddGoal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addgoal);
        mAddGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GoalListAdapter.this, AddGoal.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that worked...I now want to start an activity when that button is clicked...for some reason, startActivity cannot be resolved; thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to pass `Context` into your class. Please see my updated answer with an example of passing the `Context` in via the constructor. In the example, an activity is launched via `mContext.startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you're trying to do, but remove the code

```
 android:onClick="btnRemoveClick"
```

from your xml. that might work.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me; after some research, and looking at the above answers, I understood I needed to use getContext():

```
  @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_goals_list, null);

        }

        //use midwifefirm as item view/list

        super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


        // find in layout the practice name
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalname);

        //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("goalname"));



        mAddGoal = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addgoal);
        mAddGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), AddGoal.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }


        });

        return view;





    }
```